# Apache Mina ExecutorFilter

Tags: java, apache-mina

I am facing a strange issue with apache MINA. I have server application which is based on apache Mina framework. I am using ExecutorFilter at the server side. the application works perfectly on my machine but when I am installing it on client's machine its "throwing exception".

Here is the error I am getting on client's machine:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter.<init>(II[Lorg/apache/mina/core/session/IoEventType;)V
```

This is how I am referring it in my code-

```
new ExecutorFilter(1, 100, IoEventType.MESSAGE_RECEIVED)
```

There are 2 differences I found between my system and client's machine -
Java Version ==> My 1.6.0_26 / Client's 1.6.0_24
Operating system ==> my XP SP3/ Client's Windows 2003 server SP 2

Can any one shed any light on any possible solution?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have the same mina version on both systems?

Comment: Exactly same set up, I have copied the same set up on several machines. It works on all the machine except Client's machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, a `NoSuchMethodError` (or `NoClassDefFoundError`, `AbstractMethodError`) at runtime almost always indicates a library version mismatch. Make sure your client uses the exact same Mina version, and make sure there does not happen to be a second version of the Mina JAR on the classpath confusing things.

Comment: Oops, your comment about copying wasn't there when I wrote this. Never mind then.

Comment: Thanks I got it, I saw another mina jar file of lower version in system class path. I will solve it now.